# Moving DIV inside of elements

Tags: jquery, html

Considering something like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">Item 1</div>
  <div class="items">Item 2</div>
  <div class="items">Item 3</div>
  <div class="items">Item 4</div>
  <div class="items">Item 5</div>
  <div class="items">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to put one DIV if wrapper is > 3 and other if wrapper is > 5

```
  <div class="d1">ADS</div>
  <div class="d2">ADS</div>
```

My code should look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">Item 1</div>
  <div class="items">Item 2</div>
  <div class="items">Item 3</div>
  <div class="d1">ADS</div>
  <div class="items">Item 4</div>
  <div class="items">Item 5</div>
  <div class="d2">ADS</div>
  <div class="items">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

I'm using appendTo() method of jQuery, but think that I can't reach the solution that I want.

```
$(function() {
  var numItems = $('.wrapper').length;
  if(numItems > 3) {
      $(".d1").appendTo(".wrapper .items");
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't something you necessarily have control over, but it would be a little easier if you were to insert an element after every nth element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `nth-child` selector and `insertAfter` function

```js
$(".d1").insertAfter('.items:nth-child(3)');
$(".d2").insertAfter('.items:nth-child(6)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">Item 1</div>
  <div class="items">Item 2</div>
  <div class="items">Item 3</div>
  <div class="items">Item 4</div>
  <div class="items">Item 5</div>
  <div class="items">Item 6</div>
</div>
 <div class="d1">ADS</div>
  <div class="d2">ADS</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    $('.d1').insertAfter('.items:nth-child(2n+1)');
```

If you want to insert a div after every odd items. You can hardcode n to any integer of your requirement. Like to insert after third element, replace n with 1, i.e 2*1 + 1 = 3 equivalent to

```
 $('.d1').insertAfter('.items:nth-child(3)');
```

Similarly n=2 for 5th element. n=3 for 7th element and so on..